# Change the picture into another picture in relation to hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Goal**:
When you have your cursor over the image, it should be changed into this image:

[image]

**Problem**:
I don't know how to solve in this context.

The source code is taken from this plugin:

[**scrollup-jquery-plugin**](https://markgoodyear.com/2013/01/scrollup-jquery-plugin)

A simplified version is located in [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sL3c1v12/14)

```
    $(function(){
       $.scrollUp({scrollText: false });
    });
```

I have not changed anything in the javascript source code.

Please help me into this.

Answer (score 1):

User the `:hover` notation:

```
    #scrollUp:hover {
       background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sweets/128/lollypop_blue_candy.png");
    }
```

And for the future: This should not be that hard to find for yourself. Sometimes using a search engine with the keyword you have in mind + "CSS" yields pretty solid results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover) pseudo.

Ref:

> The :hover CSS pseudo-class matches when the user designates an
>   element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it.
>   This style may be overridden by any other link-related pseudo-classes,
>   that is :link, :visited, and :active, appearing in subsequent rules.
>   In order to style appropriately links, you need to put the :hover rule
>   after the :link and :visited rules but before the :active one, as
>   defined by the LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active.

Code:

```
#scrollUp:hover {
    background-image: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/sweets/128/lollypop_blue_candy.png");
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y0ofjye1/

Comment: Also either use the same size image or you can use `background-size: cover;` to cover whatever `height` `width` you give to your `scroll-to-top` button.